# How to remove "Apps" folder but keep "Programs" folder on start menu, Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, classic-shell

I'm running Win 10 Pro v1903, 64-bit. How can I remove the "Apps" folder from my start menu, while keeping the "Programs" folder and keeping the Classic Shell Menu installed?

[image]

Comment: What _Apps_ folder, what _Programs_ folder? If possible, please provide a screenshot.

Comment: Screenshot now added.

Comment: @ruffle : Uninstall classic shell menu. :) Or maybe you can use this software's settings to not display Apps? (from Customize Start Menu tab) You are aware that your start menu is not the default one for W10, right?

Comment: Yes. I have now mentioned Classic Shell Menu in the question. How do I find the Customise Start Menu tab?

Comment: Probably right click

Comment: Thanks. I've done it now: right-click on Start button, then Settings | Special Items and uncheck Show Apps Menu.

Comment: You can answer your own question.